# C++: Giving unknown class variable to template

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a class ABC and I want give an unknown class variable to its template, like that:

```
template < v >
class ABC
{
// do something
};
```

Of course above code doesn't work (there wasn't type of parameter **v**). Have You got any ideas to fix that? I don't want give type of variable **v** to the template.

There are two functions, which types are different. How to use both functions in class template below?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Types of functions max1 and min1 are different!
int max1(int a, int b){ return a>b?a:b; }
int& min1(int a, int b){ return a<b?a:b; }

template<typename _T, _T(function)(_T,_T)>
class ABC
{
      public:
      _T a, b;
      _T get()
      {
                 return function(a, b);       
      }        
};

ABC <int, max1> abc; // <- If You write "ABC <int, min1> abc;", error comes! How fix this?

int main()
    {
    abc.a = 3;
    abc.b = 8;
    cout << abc.get() << '\n';      
    cin.get();      
    return 0;      
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe it'll help if you show us how you'd like to use this.

Comment: Maybe you seems to think the variable are declared in `template<...>` and the function bodies are put in the class body ?

Comment: If you change _T (function)(_T, _T) to _T(*)(_T, _T) does it change anything?

Comment: Err, what you're doing is not possible. The only things that can go inside template lists are types and integral constants. max1 is neither a type nor a constant.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Seems to be irrelevant, but the question was very unclear at the beginning...</sub>

```
template < v >
```

must be

```
template < typename v >
```

or

```
template < class v >
```

`typename` is preferable.

---

Regarding your edit: the problem is, that `min1` returns `&`. If you remove it, then you may have:

```
#include <iostream>

int max1(int a, int b){ return a>b?a:b; }
int min1(int a, int b){ return a<b?a:b; }

template<typename _T, _T(*function)(_T,_T)>
class ABC
{
public:
      _T a, b;
      _T get() { return function(a, b); }        
};

int main()
{
    ABC <int, max1> abc;
    ABC <int, min1 > def;

    abc.a = def.a = 3;
    abc.b = def.b = 8;

    std::cout << abc.get() << '\n';
    std::cout << def.get() << '\n';      

    return 0;      
}
```

and this will print `8 3`

Comment: In this use, `typename` is strictly equivalent to `class`, although I also prefer `typename`.

Comment: Yep, it's absolutely the same in this case. That's why I wrote "preferable"

Comment: I want give variable, not type of variable.

Comment: @greego - maybe you should give an example about what you mean. Apparently, nobody understands your issue.

Comment: @KirilKirov I've edited my post above. 
I want use **both** functions, however they types are different. How do this?

Comment: @greego - OK, see my edit. If it satisfies you, I'll flag the question for reopening.